# Split array into intervals with given limits

Tags: python, numpy

From an array, how to take only the parts within given intervals? E.g.
from

```
x = np.linspace(0,10,51)
intervals = [[2, 2.5], [8.1, 9]]
```

get

```
[[2, 2.2, 2.4], [8.2,  8.4,  8.6, 8.8]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use only numpy like this;

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,10,51)
intervals = [[2, 2.5], [8.1, 9]]

[x[np.argwhere( np.logical_and(x >= y[0], x < y[1])).flatten()] for y in intervals]

>>> [array([2. , 2.2, 2.4]), array([8.2, 8.4, 8.6, 8.8])]
```

`np.argwhere` is used in combination with `np.logical_and` to search where the interval is true. Then the result of `np.argwhere` is used to select these elements.

`.flatten()` is used since the input was 1D, but the `argwhere` returns 2D positions.

EDIT:

This method is easier to understand when you see it in someones code the first time. Works the same.

```
[x[(x >= y[0]) & (x < y[1])] for y in intervals]
>>> [array([2. , 2.2, 2.4]), array([8.2, 8.4, 8.6, 8.8])]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import bisect
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,10,51)
intervals = [[2, 2.5], [8.1, 9]]

indexs = []
for left_idx,right_idx in intervals:
    indexs.append(slice(bisect.bisect_left(x, left_idx), bisect.bisect_left(x, right_idx), None))
    
print([x[index] for index in indexs])
```

```
[array([2. , 2.2, 2.4]), array([8.2, 8.4, 8.6, 8.8])]
```

===============================================================

Here's an update to my answer on Time Complexity Analysis.

First, generate a big dataset.

```
import numpy as np
from random import sample

x = np.linspace(0,1000000,50001)
intervals = sorted(sample(x.tolist(), 10000))
intervals = [intervals[idx:idx+2] for idx in range(0,len(intervals),2)]
```

Next, calculate operation time.

```
import bisect
import time

begin = time.time()
indexs = []
for left_idx,right_idx in intervals:
    indexs.append(slice(bisect.bisect_left(x, left_idx), bisect.bisect_left(x, right_idx), None))
data = [x[index] for index in indexs]

print(f"{time.time() - begin}")
>>> 0.022243022918701172
```

Finally, you will have a faster solution.